# SQL joining tables and merging columns of different type

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may not be usual and probably is not good thing to do, but I would like to know if it is possible. So let's say I got two tables that look like this:

```
T1: A--B--C--D     T2:  A--B--E--F
    1 |2 |3 |4         '1'|'1'|1|1
    2 |2 |1 |4         '2'|'2'|2|2
```

Is there a way to join those two tables and to get in the result table merged columns `A` and `B` and also separated columns `C, D, E, F`. The main point is that column A and B in the `T1` are of `Integer` type and in `T2` of `varchar` and that is why I want those columns in result table to become `varchar` too.
The result table should look something like this:

```
T3: A--B--C--D--E--F     
   '1'|'2'|3 |4 |? |?        
   '2'|'2'|1 |4 |? |?
   '1'|'1'|? |? |1 |1
   '2'|'2'|? |? |2 |2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `convert()` to change the data type, and `quotename()` to wrap the integer in single quotes like the `varchar` data type in a `full outer join`:

```
select 
    a = coalesce(t2.a,quotename(convert(varchar(5),t1.a),''''))
  , b = coalesce(t2.b,quotename(convert(varchar(5),t1.b),''''))
  , t1.c
  , t1.d
  , t2.e
  , t2.f
from t1
  full outer join t2
    on convert(varchar(5),t1.a) = t2.a
   and convert(varchar(5),t1.b) = t2.b
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HSDSS14733

returns:

```
+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
|  a  |  b  |  c   |  d   |  e   |  f   |
+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
| '1' | '2' | 3    | 4    | NULL | NULL |
| '2' | '2' | 1    | 4    | NULL | NULL |
| '1' | '1' | NULL | NULL | 1    | 1    |
| '2' | '2' | NULL | NULL | 2    | 2    |
+-----+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: That's just what I needed! I'm very happy this is possible, thank you very much. The problem was I am getting `varchars` from other table in this form: `#1#2#32#` etc. And that is why it is much easier for me to convert `int` to `varchar` and later when I need to filter the result I am just going to use `like %1%` to find out if there is number 1 in column A for example.

Comment: @Verthosa I have to wait 2 minutes more before I do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `full join`:

```
select coalesce(cast(t1.a as varchar(255)), t2.a) as a, 
       coalesce(cast(t1.b as varchar(255)), t2.b) as b,
       t1.c, t1.d, t2.e, t2.f
from t1 full join
     t2
     on t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b;
```

Note that mixing of data types can make the joins much slower.  In addition, you can get type conversion errors if the values are not actually compatible (i.e. if the string columns do not contain numbers).

EDIT:

I don't actually like implicit conversion, so you can explicitly do the conversion:

```
select coalesce(cast(t1.a as varchar(255)), t2.a) as a, 
       coalesce(cast(t1.b as varchar(255)), t2.b) as b,
       t1.c, t1.d, t2.e, t2.f
from t1 full join
     t2
     on cast(t1.a as varchar(255)) = t2.a and cast(t1.b as varchar(255)) = t2.b;
```

Comment: This looks great, but you haven't used `convert` or `cast`. is the SQL going to do it by itself to convert integers to varchar?

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use `UNION ALL`. may be you get some performance.

Also please correct if any type conversion error.

```
select cast(a as varchar)a,cast(b as varchar)b,cast(c as varchar)c
,cast(d as varchar)d,null e,null f 
from T1
union ALL
select a,b,null c,null d, e,f 
from T2
```